# No menu bar in Digikam on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, menu

Title says it all, basically.

In Digikam, I cannot (I think) access the settings without using the menu bar. **All screenshots I see of this program have a menu bar. But on my system, I cannot get it to appear**:

[image]

The "digikam" dropdown has no useful options.

I would assume this is a basic setting, but I've searched everywhere (settings, `gnome-tweaks`, `gnome-tweak-tool`, `compizconfig`, ...) and cannot get it to appear.

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: did this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050378/for-ubuntu-18-04-is-there-a-way-to-show-drop-down-menus-for-a-certain-applicati  work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had a look, and it doesn't seem to solve my problem. I've tried installing and enabling the `gnome global menu` extension, even if it's no longer supported, but the menu bar is still not visible. Also, the post seems to talk mainly about apps that are native to gnome; digiKam is native to KDE.

Comment: Also, the information in that post seems outdated, as the app menu [is going away](https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2018/10/09/farewell-application-menus/)

Comment: Can you show please `gsettings list-recursively | grep menubar`

Comment: @ElRudi it isn't outdated yet, because the appmenu is used in the Ubuntu LTS and this is the recommended Ubuntu version to be installed. Also the appmenu is a Gtk3+ feature and not matter if gnome-shell remove the appmenu implementation or not, it continued be part of Gtk3+. So, it's an existent feature anyway, not matter if rigth now notone is using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default key combination to toggle the menu bar for digikam 6.4.0 is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Actually, I'll be damned but that works! I'll add it to the list of things to check when searching for menu items. (Which already includes pressing `Alt` to make the menu bar briefly appear like in Firefox, having an app menu instead of a menu bar like in some gnome native apps, and always having a menu bar present like in Inkscape and Gimp.) I feel a bit stupid haha but in my defence - I didn't see this option when right-clicking on any toolbar, so I didn't think there might be a shortcut for it. I've since learned `Ctrl+M` is standard (?) in KDE apps, so I'll try it more often. Many thanks!!

Comment: I'm really glad this helped, sometimes the simplest things are easy to overlook!

Comment: solved the issue for me 3 years later thanks :) !