# Ubuntu 19.10 - show application's menu choices: e.g. file, edit, etc

Tags: menu, 19.10

I seem to have forgotten how to do this, and I don't think I'm phrasing it right for a google search, nor do I see a keyboard shortcut for this. I'd like to be able to show an application's menu (such as file, edit, etc.)

Does anyone know how to do this for Ubuntu 19.10?

---

EDIT:

To clarify, in Unity we had the "menu bar" per application, which exposed application-specific dropdowns beyond the dropdown that appears in the upper left in GNOME shell. Here's an example of a tutorial that deals with the "menu bar" in Unity: https://www.howtogeek.com/187999/how-to-enable-local-menus-in-ubuntu-14.04/

I prefer to continue to use GNOME shell (or the current Ubuntu-flavored equivalent, that's fine) but I would like a way to display the "menu bar" options for an application.

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/961161/how-do-i-disable-client-side-decoration-globally-in-gnome/999663#999663 helps

Comment: Did you try to select another desktop manager at **login screen** as shown in the image at the following question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136127/which-desktop-manager-to-use-in-19-04

Comment: I think the user is actually asking... what function key is used to drop down the application menu? I don't think it's documented along with the normal keyboard shortcuts... but it's something like special_key+function_key (ie: alt-F2).

Comment: Please clarify what you exactly want to know.

Comment: does not the alt key on its own open the 'menu' for the active application? it does for me.

Comment: @pierrely - Yes, for some applications (such as Firefox) but not all, at least not in my experience.

Comment: if an appmenu can be accessed with the mouse, the I would use  a shortcut key for the command to select it. or a script for something like the following.
to get the coordinates for top left, or where the app menu is. assumes that that is in the same place for all windows. and need to account for window decorations.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/how-do-i-find-the-window-dimensions-and-position-accurately-including-decoration

xdotool mousemove <locationtopleft>  && xdotool click 1

Comment: also if the location is different for different apps, you can customise the script for that like.

Comment: well a lot of my comment was cut out somehow    ...    ,  xdotool search --desktop 0 --class ,     getactivewindow     are hints . you get the ID of the current window then test for the ID of the class (eg Konsole, Firefox etc)  in the script then choose where to click the mouse to correspond to your menu. make a shortcut key to it. I will have to start saving my long comments to local file now. probably too many edits and I forgot to save edits before PC crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! This is a pervasive issue, and not one with an easy fix or explanation. I'll link to this excellent discussion on the topic, and answer my question.

[For Ubuntu 18.04, is there a way to show drop-down menus for a certain applications in a menu bar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050378/for-ubuntu-18-04-is-there-a-way-to-show-drop-down-menus-for-a-certain-applicati)