# GNOME Global Application Menu highlights

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, globalmenu

I Want a menubar in GNOME 3.20, and have found [Gnome Global Application Menu (hud for GNOME)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/).  The problem with this extension is, the highlighting stays there, and it unselects the window that you were on.

Can somebody please tell me how to turn off the hover when my mouse isn't on it, and keep the window selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension is discontinued and the last supported version of gnome-shell to that extension was the 3.28 (Ubuntu 18.04). But the link that you already provided have only support until 3.24. If you want support for 3.28, you should download the extension from this link: https://github.com/jiqing112/Gnome-Global-AppMenu/archive/master.zip.

There are no way to change how the extension is working without change the code. So, only a fork of that extension should change that fact or otherwise a new release, but apparently this will not be occurs.

**Disclaimer**: I was the original author of the extension and then who discontinued it.

Comment: Why was it discontinued? Where was the difficulty?

Comment: @yman I answer this here: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/getting-global-menu-back/5713/9, probably you want to read this also, because is a general exaplantion of how things are in the time that was discontinued: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050378/for-ubuntu-18-04-is-there-a-way-to-show-drop-down-menus-for-a-certain-applicati/1050565#1050565 I have also comments related with that in reddit: https://www.reddit.com/user/lestcape and other places out there. Search on google for "lestacape"+"global menu".